# D3: How to insert an HTML element into the DOM?

Tags: d3.js

[`d3.insert`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-insert), [`d3.append`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-append) and [`d3.html`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-html) are three ways to insert new elements into the DOM using d3.

However, they all expect HTML text and create new nodes. In my use case I already have a DOM element ready (for the curious: obtained by `$compile`'ing AngularJS snippet) and am at a loss how to add that. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs for [selection.append](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-append) and [selection.insert](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-insert), these functions' argument can be "specified either as a constant string or as a function that returns the DOM element to append".

So if you have a node already assigned to variable `my_node` you can just do this:

```
selection.append(function() { return my_node; });
```

Comment: Duh, good point.  I tried that before but didn't realize that it wasn't working because `$compile` of AngularJS was giving me an array of nodes, not a single node.  Thanks!